# breezejs : configuring service for CORS

Tags: cors, breeze

I can access my web api service using a standard jquery ajax call:

```
$.ajax('http://service/method', {
contentType: 'application/json',
type: 'GET',
xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  }
})
```

On the server side the webconfig file is configured as such:

```
 <customHeaders>
    <clear/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:1502" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type,X-Requested-With, Authorization" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
```

For now, I'm trying to reach the service from a local website running on port 1502.

However, when using breeze, I don't see how I can specify the withCredential parameter, and as a result I get a 401 error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [Breeze "ajax adapter"](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/customizing-ajax). The following approach would add "withCredentials" to every Breeze XHR request.

```
// get the current default Breeze AJAX adapter
var ajaxAdapter = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance("ajax");
// merge 'withCredentials' into the settings Breeze passes to the jQuery.ajax method
ajaxAdapter.defaultSettings = {
      xhrFields: {
          withCredentials: true
      }
};
```

You could make a more clever adapter if you need to add this (or other information) to the request conditionally (e.g., for certain URLs and not others).

Comment: thanks for helping. I've edited my post to show you my service intialization code. I'm using a dataService and I don't see how I can re-use the code you gave me. I don't think I use the "ajax" adapter in my case, or do I ?

Comment: oups sorry, I replied too quickly. It actually works with your code. Fantastic, you've helped me fixing my CORS issue ! thanks a lot

Comment: I was hoping this would work for me, but when it did not, I tried to follow the link to see if there is more info.  But the link is dead....

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above method and it does not seem to be working as of BreezeJS 1.6.3.

However, I was able to get it to work with a slight change. Here is my working code:

```
// set credentials on
var ajaxAdapter = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance('ajax');
ajaxAdapter.defaultSettings = {
    withCredentials: true
};
```